# How to print only a static number of integers from a string

Tags: java

My program produces an ascii calendar with some events that are stored in an array. I need a way so that in the blank space of the calendar instead it prints the width of the calendar - 1 characters per line. How would I make it so that it only prints (lets say width = 5) the first 4 character, then the next 4.
Note: the program uses a for loop to make each line so it must be one statement that is repeated to print all of the characters in the string.

Example of desired outcome:

```
======================================================================
|         |        1|        2|        3|        4|        5|        6|
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
======================================================================
|        7|        8|        9|       10|       11|       12|       13|
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
======================================================================
|       14|       15|       16|       17|       18|       19|       20|
|         |St. Patri|         |         |         |         |         |
|         |ks day   |         |         |         |         |         |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
======================================================================
|       21|       22|       23|       24|       25|       26|       27|
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
======================================================================
|       28|         |         |         |         |         |         |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
======================================================================
```

Code so far:

```
 public static void drawRow(int row) {
  int dayofweek = startingDayOfWeek(month);
  int daysinmonth = daysInMonth(month);  
  int dayspassed = 1;  
     for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) { 
        System.out.print("|");
        for(int a = 1; a <= 7; a++) {
           
           int length=String.valueOf(10).length();
           for(int j = 1; j < Width - length; j++) {
              System.out.print(" ");
           }
           if(dayofweek > 0) {
              System.out.print("  ");
              dayofweek--;   
           }
           
           else {
              if(dayspassed < 10) {
                 System.out.print(" ");
              }
              
              if(daysinmonth >  0) {    
                 System.out.print(dayspassed); 
                 daysinmonth--;
                 dayspassed++;
              }
              else {
                 System.out.print("  ");
              }
           }
           System.out.print("|");
        } 
     
     for(int t = 1; t < (Width /2); t++) {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("|");
        for(int h = 1; h<=7; h++) {         
           for(int f = 1; f <= Width - 1; f++) {
                 eventChecker(month,day);
                 if(eventCheck == true) {

                 // part where I need it to either print an event if 
                 // there is one, or line wrap the event.

                 System.out.print(" ");
           }
        System.out.print("|");
        }
     }
     
     System.out.println();
     for(int e = 1; e <= Width * 7; e++) {
        System.out.print("=");
     }
  System.out.println();
  }
  dayspassed = 1;
  daysinmonth = daysInMonth(month);
  dayofweek = startingDayOfWeek(month);
```

I've marked the part I need to modify with a comment.

Comment: Could you share with us (in code) what you have tried on your own?

Comment: I'm not sure how to even do it, my only ideas is to have the string get split into groups, and having the size of the groups based on the width of the calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this will return the correct character for each cell:

```
private static char getEventChar(String event, int row, int column, int width) {
    // we are interested in the n-th character in this String
    int n = row * width + column; 
    if (n >= event.length()) {
        return ' '; // if we passed the end of the name return space-character
    }
    return event.charAt(n);
}
```